# How do I get google to display my link as example.com NOT example.com/

Tags: apache, .htaccess, seo

Currently google shows my site link as...

```
example.com/
```

...however, I would like it to be displayed as...

```
example.com
```

I do have the following meta data

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com" />
```

...and the following is my htaccess file...

```
IndexIgnore * 

ErrorDocument 400 /error 
ErrorDocument 401 /error 
ErrorDocument 403 /error 
ErrorDocument 404 /error 
ErrorDocument 500 /error 

RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase / 

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/ 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=301,L] 

RewriteRule ^(home|cv|handouts|links|contact|copyright|cv)/?$ /index.php?module=home&action=$1 
RewriteRule ^(log(in|out))/?$ /index.php?module=authentication&action=$1 

RewriteRule ^photos/?$ /index.php?module=gallery&action=album&album=general 
RewriteRule ^gallery/?$ /index.php?module=gallery&action=album&album=general 
RewriteRule ^gallery/([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?module=gallery&action=album&album=$1 
RewriteRule ^gallery/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?module=gallery&action=album&album=$1$&page=$2 
RewriteRule ^gallery/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?module=gallery&action=item&album=$1$&page=$2&item=$3 

RewriteRule ^release/?$ /index.php?module=release&action=release 
RewriteRule ^error/?$ /index.php?module=error&action=error
```

... and with the htaccess file being as above, I note that visiting either example.com or example.com/index.php redirects to example.com/ which perhaps could be the problem??

With all that being said, and any ideas on how to get google to display my link as example.com NOT example.com/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry I don't have an answer for you, I was just wondering why this is important? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run a [Google Search](http://www.google.com/search?q=google). **Every** single website in their database has a trailing slash after the domain name. The only time they don't have a trailing slash is when it's after a path component. The path component trailing slash is up to each website's administrator to decide.

In the future they might hide the trailing slash like they do in Chrome but for now there's nothing *you* can do about.